# How chnage image size before uploaded on server

Tags: php, mysql

I want to change image size before uploaded on server/mysql database, As its for member, so member can uploaded big images in size and i want to prevent and assign a new image size of their images.

I need it in PHP.

Thanks

Comment: If all else fails and nobody gives you an answer, you could always........... as a last resort of course [Read the ? Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resizing an image in php without uploading first is not possible as php only runs on the server side. It can be done with js though, there are a lot of libraries that can help you out, like Jimp, Jcrop and Processing.js.

If you really want it in php than the image has to be uploaded first and than you will be able the resize the image with imagecopyresized function for example.

The php manual has an example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php)

Comment: I can not resize image before finally uploading a file on server/folder ? I don't think hosting company will allow me for Library. Basically when i am uploading more than 5 MB files, Its not uploading on server, it seems its uploaded but in actuall its not uploaded, but small images does. Any help ?

Comment: It's a php setting that allows the hosting provider to limit the max size you can upload. You might can override this, but you need to ask your hosting company for that. The other option as I suggested earlier is the JS solution. Maybe another good JS library for handling this is [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) which also allows you the specify the max resolution.

Comment: Basically I m using same jQuery file upload (multiple file), but I didn't find a way to decrease the size before uploaded on server. Do you know how to do it or can help me in this ?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Client-side-Image-Resizing

Comment: I have tried lot of things, finally added latest Jquery file upload and its  working now! Thanks!